# Sorting ArrayList of objects by float

Tags: java, processing

I have an arraylist of stockprices each stockprices has a name, stock exchange, price and date.

I am trying to organise the arraylist by prices which are floats.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

According to the requirements of JDK 1.7, the results must be the same when reversing the params' position

```
comparator.compare(a, b) == -comparator.compare(b, a)
```

So, subtract will be wrong, I think the below code is the easiest way to sort float arrays

```
Collections.sort(Arrays, new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return Float.compare(o1.getFloatValue(), o2.getFloatValue());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `java.util.Collections.sort()` and specify your own `java.util.Comparator`.

Comment: thank you. Does this taken into account 28 is bigger then -123?

Comment: @Vuzuggu, you define the rules for the sort in the `Comparator`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement your own Comparator or make your stocprices extends Comparable

```
Collections.sort(stockPricesArrayList, new Comparator<StockPrice>() {

    public int compare(StockPrice p1, StockPrices p2) {
         return (int) p1.getPrice()-p2.getPrice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your class StockPrice you can implement Comparable. It would look like:

```
public class StockPrice implements Comparable<StockPrice> {

    // All your code here

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StockPrice another) {
        // price fields should be Float instead of float
        return this.price.compareTo(another.price);
    }

}
```

Then you can use `Collections.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a class for storing your prices. The easiest way here is to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in this class and return someting like `Float.compare(this.price, other.price)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the Comparable interface, and define the compareTo() method for your class. Once done you can have an arraylist and sort it. See this [link](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparable-example.html) for an example.
Few more importants links are 
[another example](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/641-example-for-a-class-implementing-comparable-i/) and 
[diff between comparable and comparator useful information](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html)